How can I solve for $r$ in this algebraic equation?
I want to find the critical point of a modified Lamb-Oseen equation,
$$u_\theta (r,t)= \frac{\omega_0 R_0^2}{r}\left(1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right)$$
in the domain, $0<r\leq R_f$. The boundary function, $B(r)$, is, $$ B(r)=1-\frac{r}{R_f}$$
This fluid vortex equation in cylindrical coordinates is a stochastic distribution of azimuthal velocities confined in a cylinder of radius $R_f$ (defined within $0<r\leq R_f$), propagating by the function, $R(t)$. Finding the local maximum of the original Lamb-Oseen equation,
$$u_\theta (r,t)= \frac{\omega_0 R_0^2}{r}\left(1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}} \right)$$
involves taking the partial derivative $u_\theta$ w.r.t $r$, setting this equal to zero, and using the Lambert-W function to solve for $r$.
$$r=R(t)\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)} = 1.120906422779\dots R(t)$$
Here is my attempt to solve for $r$:
\begin{align*} 
\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}=0
&= \omega_0 R_0^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\frac{1}{r}\left(1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{r^2}-\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left( \frac{1}{r}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{r^2}-\left( -\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{r^2}-\left( -\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{r^2}-\left( -\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)}+ \frac{1}{r} \left(-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B'(r)-\frac{2r}{R^2}B(r) \right)e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{r^2} +\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)}+ \frac{r}{R^2}B'(r)e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} +\frac{2}{R^2}B(r) e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \\
\frac{1}{r^2}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)}\right) &= \frac{r}{R^2}B'(r)e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} +\frac{2}{R^2}B(r) e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \\
1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} &= rB'(r)\frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} +2B(r) \frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \\
1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} &= rB'(r)\frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} +2B(r) \frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} 
\end{align*}
Using the substitution, $$n^2=\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)$$, and these renditions of $n^2$, $$B(r)=\frac{n^2 R^2}{r^2}$$
$$B'(r)= -\frac{2n^2 R^2}{r^3}$$ the equation is solved as,
\begin{align*}
1-e^{-n^2} &= rB'(r)\frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-n^2} +2B(r) \frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-n^2} \\
&= r\left(-\frac{2n^2 R^2}{r^3} \right)\frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-n^2} +2\left(\frac{n^2 R^2}{r^2} \right) \frac{r^2}{R^2}e^{-n^2} \\
&= 0 \\
1&=e^{-n^2} \\
\ln(1) &= \ln{e^{-n^2}}\\
n&=0 \\
\therefore r&=R_f
\end{align*}
One could argue that $r=R_f$ is a solution to the partial derivative, though it is not the only solution.
Question: How can I solve for $r$ (given that $0<r<R_f$) in the Lambert W form,
$$-\frac{1}{3}e^{-\frac{1}{3}}=-\left(\frac{2}{3}\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}-\frac{r^{3}}{R^{2}R_{f}}+\frac{1}{3}\right)e^{-\left(\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}-\frac{r^{3}}{R^{2}R_{f}}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$
The modified Lamb-Oseen vortex has one critical point (as a function w.r.t time, $t$) that I estimated to be,
$$r=\frac{R_{f}}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(R(t)\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{11}}\frac{2}{R_{f}}\right)$$
Which if solved for the radial propagation function,
$$R(t)=\sqrt{\frac{11}{4\pi}}\frac{R_{f}}{2} \operatorname{erf}^{-1} \left(\frac{2r}{R_f} \right) $$
the path of the vortex's critical point over time $t$ is obtained:
$$u_\theta (r)= \frac{\omega_0 R_0^2}{r}\left(1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{11}{4\pi}}\frac{R_{f}}{2} \operatorname{erf}^{-1} \left(\frac{2r}{R_f} \right)\right)^2}B(r)} \right)$$
I made a desmos calculator of the approximation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jlbpanboqg
